# Intuition for singular matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

This might be a poorly formed question, but do there exist any intuitive ways to look at a matrix and conclude, at a glance, that it *might* be singular?

The comments were helpful.  A better formed question might be: What are some general characteristics that either guarantee singularity or at least make it worth my while to try and see if it is?

Comment: I think this really is too vague. Obviously if some row or column is all $0$ then the matrix is singular, of if two rows and/or two columns coincide.  Beyond that....

Comment: If you can't see a reason that it has to be nonsingular, you could suspect that it **might** be singular.  For example, a strictly diagonally dominant matrix is nonsingular, and so is an upper or lower triangular matrix with all diagonal elements nonzero.

Comment: Do you mention a particular class of matrices? Laplacian matrix of an electrical circuit is singular. Any consistent matrix in the theory of parwise comparison is singular. But in general, the answer is not evident.

Comment: All these are good answers to the question I would have asked if I had known better which to ask.  :)  Thanks!  My linear algebra education is years behind me and now that my work actually calls for it, I'm trying to muster up some "common sense" about it.  Could anyone comment on why these are obvious or evident, to shore up my intuition?

Comment: @FrankHarris it might help us if you provided a bit more context.  How is it exactly that singular matrices have come up in your work?